# Intuitive way to view most active fork in GitHub

Tags: github, github-api

This is a network graph of a GitHub repository:

[image: github fork graph]

There is no indication of which fork has the most stars and watchers. The commits may be simple updates to documentation files, for example.

Is there a way to evaluate forks in GitHub to determine which ones are more active/popular?

Comment: additional up to date online tool to achieve that:
https://techgaun.github.io/active-forks/index.html

Comment: http://gitpop2.herokuapp.com/ was another tool I found that was effective. I also edited this question in hopes it could be reopened, but even though the edit was approved the question remains closed.

Comment: https://techgaun.github.io/active-forks/index.html was helpful for me.

Comment: You can see last commit date, diff and get the commit-diff details (commit message and link to this commit) with this tool: https://lukasznojek.com/projects/active-github-forks

As GitHub limits the requests, you'll have to provide a Token.
See [this request](https://github.community/t/how-to-draw-attention-for-active-forks-functionality/152515/2) on GH feedback

Comment: https://andremiras.github.io/gitpop3/ or https://gitpop2.herokuapp.com/ or search for "github fork popularity"

Comment: `gitpop2` is no longer working as of 2023.

Answer (score 25):

I don't know of one, but you could probably write one easily given the breadth of API wrappers out there. An example with `github3.py` would be

```
import github3

r = github3.repository('owner', 'repo_name')
most_watched = next(r.iter_forks(sort='watchers', number=1))
```

As best I know, you cannot sort on `stars` and repositories don't have that information returned to them. You could, however, sort on forks but you would have to do it by hand.

The above example is two lines but you can achieve the same thing like so:

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/owner/repo_name/forks?sort=watchers
```

That won't limit how many results you get, though.

Comment: how can I sort by number of commit to find the most active fork?

Comment: `iter_forks` didn't work for me; `forks` did but I don't know if that achieved the same result as you were going for.

Answer (score 2):

There is a tool created by Andre Miras that does exactly that: https://andremiras.github.io/gitpop3/

Answer (score 2):

This command will get the fork with most `watchers` which you can replace with stargazers or subscribers:

```bash
curl https://api.github.com/repos/$REPO_OWNER/$REPO_NAME/forks | jq 'max_by(.watchers_count)' | jq -cs '.[0]."full_name"'
```