# How do I find the forked repository which has the maximum stars

Tags: github

Assuming I have my repository under https://github.com/foo/bar and if bar is forked by many people. How to find the forked repository which has the maximum stars

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intuitive way to view most active fork in GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18937159/intuitive-way-to-view-most-active-fork-in-github)

Comment: Is it possible to see this in the user interface itself somehow, instead of a program

Comment: There are some website's that implement the code linked in above question. However, not sure how reliable those websites are. I've used this site quite often (first google hit...) `https://techgaun.github.io/active-forks/index.html#camptocamp/puppet-postfix`

Comment: Thanks @0stone0, very useful tool